# Extract the UIbutton value to Another UIbutton for calculation

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

```
@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let userSelect = sender.currentTitle!
    
    print(userSelect)
    
    if userSelect == "0%" {
        zeroPcnt.isSelected = true
        tenPcnt.isSelected = false
        twentyPcnt.isSelected = false
    } else if userSelect == "10%" {
        zeroPcnt.isSelected = false
        tenPcnt.isSelected = true
        twentyPcnt.isSelected = false
    } else if userSelect == "20%" {
        zeroPcnt.isSelected = false
        tenPcnt.isSelected = false
        twentyPcnt.isSelected = true
    }
    
    
}


@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    
}

@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
}
```

How do i get the value of tipChanged to calculatePressed for calculation of the tip? and also where do i find this info on Apple API?

Comment: Don't use 3 buttons. What you need is a [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

Create IBOutlet of button on which you set **tipChanged** action

**`ex: @IBOutlet var tipButton: UIButton!`**

Then you can get tipButton current text in **calculatePressed** action method.

```
@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("\(self.tipButton.currentTitle ?? "")")
}
```